# How to start this unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, timeline

i have a project that i should made it with unity. The idea is that i have to do a 3d scene when player can pick up some object and can define a movement for each one. for exemple he can pick up a character and define two point and can define more points for another character. than when he click a button the two caracter will move following the line between this points.

I can write a simple script on how to make an object follow a path but this some the path and the object should be defined in playing mode.

Sorry for my english but i hope you can help me . thank you

Comment: Please provide more details of the scene. Provide players and scripts. Your question is broad.

Comment: you might find [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) useful

Comment: in this video exemple player can select object and define a path this is cool but what i want is that animation wil start only after button click. so player can define a scenario to play with one or more character. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVTmPKeJl_Y&list=PLtO64ubTPsCMLmLKg_K_qTN2cex3ZQIYS&index=5&ab_channel=MetalStormGames